# Figure out which button[type=submit] was clicked in a multi button form

Tags: ember.js

With Ember.js, for the following case:

```
<form {{action 'save' on="submit"}}>
  <button type="submit" data-source='X'>Do X</button>
  <button type="submit" data-source='Y'>Do Y</button>
</form>
```

Inside the save() event, how do one figure out which button was clicked?

(I need the form the way it is, and I need button[type=submit] too. I know I can do 2 actions on the buttons, but I would like to fire the form native submit, if the only way is to have 2 separate actions, I'll just disappointedly manually fire the form submit on each, but there has to be an easier way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action helper will not pass jQuery event information, but you can get access to it by using the view's event handler instead. So for example you could define a submit-event handler like:

```
App.MultiButtonForm = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'form',
  submit: function(event) {
    console.log('submit with: ', event);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

{{#view App.MultiButtonForm}}
  <button type="submit" data-source='X'>Do X</button>
  <button type="submit" data-source='Y'>Do Y</button>
{{/view}}
```

See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1684 for discussion of action helper vs. view event handler

Also see this post for ideas on how to figure out what button was pressed: http://www.webmuse.co.uk/blog/using-forms-with-multiple-submit-buttons-and-jquery-events/